# Grouped boxplot with two Y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, boxplot

I want to make two boxplots with different information for the same category, with two Y axes, using GGPLOT2.
Looks like this chart below:

[image]

I have two category information (speed and angle of rotation) for the areas (AM and AR) and I want to combine these two movement patterns in a graphic grouped according to the areas.

so far my code looks like this:

```
areaveleang <- ggplot(dados2, aes(x = area)) +
        geom_boxplot(aes(y = speed, color="Bruto" ), fill = "darkblue", alpha=0.7) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = angulo_modulo), color="#a50026", position = "dodge") +
        scale_y_continuous(name = "speed (km/h)", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *6,name=expression("turn angle (graus)"))) +
                           #breaks = seq(0, 175, 25),
                           #limits=c(0, 175)) +
        scale_x_discrete(name = "Area") +
        #ggtitle("Boxplot of mean ozone by month") +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, family = "Tahoma", face = "bold"),
              text = element_text(size = 12, family = "Tahoma"),
              axis.title = element_text(face="bold"),
              axis.text.x=element_text(size = 11),
              legend.position = "bottom") +
        scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Accent")
```

Part of my data:

```
structure(list(lon = c(-38.8745, -38.8676, -38.9445, -38.9811, 
-38.9322, -38.9386), lat = c(-14.09437, -14.25664, -14.34518, 
-14.51857, -14.95994, -15.41684), bmode = c(1.396, 1.375, 1.346, 
1.248, 1.074, 1.289), bmode.5 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ID = structure(c(53L, 
53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L), .Label = c("10946.05", "20162.03", 
"21792.03", "21800.03", "21810.03", "24640.03", "24641.05", "24642.03", 
"27258.05", "27259.03", "27261.03", "27261.05", "27261.07", "33000.05", 
"37231.07", "37234.05", "37288.07", "42521.07", "50682.07", "50687.07", 
"60004.07", "81122.09", "81123.09", "81124.09", "81125.09", "81126.09", 
"84497.1", "87632.12", "87759.08", "87761.08", "87762.08", "87763.08", 
"87764.08", "87765.08", "87766.08", "87768.08", "87768.11", "87769.11", 
"87770.08", "87773.08", "87773.1", "87773.11", "87774.09", "87774.11", 
"87775.08", "87776.08", "87776.11", "87777.1", "87778.08", "87783.09", 
"88724.1", "88727.09", "111868.11", "111871.12", "112702.12", 
"112712.12", "112714.12", "120947.12", "121189.12", "121192.12", 
"121196.12", "1211931.12"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("F", "Fc", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    speed = c(0.921691675, 2.990097297, 2.137609076, 3.259383146, 
    8.173674567, 8.413534172), area = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AA", "AM", "AR"), class = "factor"), 
    angulo = c(41.027, -43.41, 29.056, 18.241, -7.125, -4.702
    ), angle_rel = c(0.7160619, -0.7576522, 0.5071251, 0.3183724, 
    -0.1243479, -0.08206201), bat.depth = c(-45L, -397L, -32L, 
    -29L, -21L, -3L), dist = c(5.53015005, 17.94058378, 12.82565446, 
    19.55629887, 49.0420474, 50.48120503), angulo_modulo = c(41.027, 
    43.41, 29.056, 18.241, 7.125, 4.702), curva = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("curva", "reta"), class = "factor")), row.names = 2:7, class = "data.frame")
```

PS: Sorry for my poor english, I hope you can understand my question xD

Comment: Hey Anne, just to clarify ggplot2 is very limited with respect of producing two y axis. So if you really need two y axis, you will have a hard time. See this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether I got you right but maybe this what you are looking for:

1. To get the scale of the secondary axis right you have to apply the inverse transformation on your data, i.e. as your are multiplying by 6 you have to divide `angulo_modulo` by 6 in the data.
2. To get the two boxplots dodged I would suggest to use `tidyr::pivot_longer` so that your two variables become two categories of one variable which by default is named `name` while the values go to `value`. This way you can map `value` on `y` and `name` on `color`, `alpha` and `fill`. By default `ggplot2` will give you two side-by-side boxplots per area.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dados2 %>% 
  mutate(angulo_modulo = angulo_modulo / 6) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(speed, angulo_modulo)) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("speed", "angulo_modulo"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = area)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(y = value, color = name, alpha = name, fill = name)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "speed (km/h)", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 6, name = expression("turn angle (graus)"))) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Area") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(angulo_modulo = "darkblue", speed = "#a50026")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.7, 1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, family = "sans", face = "bold"),
        text = element_text(size = 12, family = "sans"),
        axis.title = element_text(face="bold"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size = 11),
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Accent")
```

[image]

Comment: It's exactly what I need! Thanks @Stefan